# Get index of row in GridView Control in Asp.net if i have a value of a cell from this row.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have add a grid view control in my form and fill by the DataTable.
And I create first column of every row as a link button and set same onclick event. Then I can get the text of this linkbutton.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DocName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DocName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocName") %>' OnClick="DocNameClick"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to get the whole row if user click the linkbutton of any row in the click event.

```
protected void DocNameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
     string name = btn.Text;
 }
```

Comment: Using a custom user control might be one easier option...depends on the data actually

Answer (score 0):

You get the `GridViewRow` (hence all other controls in this `TemplateField` via `FindControl`) by casting the [`NamingContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) propertery of the button:

```
protected void DocNameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) btn.NamingContainer;
    // use row.FindControl("ControlID") to get controls in other columns ...
    int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
    string name = btn.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DocNameClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    //Get the row that contains this button
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
}
```

Comment: yep, but too late ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get row `index` by following code

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow ;
int index = row.RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to you link the commandargument

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'
```

And in your method use it

```
protected void DocNameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
    string name = btn.Text;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Edit: int parse on commandargument

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
protected void DocName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
    string name = btn.Text;
}
```

Comment: This is practically identical to what OP already has. How does this solve the problem?